# Command line command to get last block hash

Tags: go-ethereum, command-line

In order to know last block hash in bitcoin I can just call

`bitcoin-cli getbestblockhash`

from command line.

Is there something like that in ethereum or I should use RPC and curl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your node is running, you can use:

```
 geth --exec 'eth.getBlock(eth.blockNumber).hash' attach
```

If it is not running, then there is no way to be synchronized,
so you cannot get this information.